# What examples of size unreachable sets in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

Lets denote any set that is "the set of all strictly smaller subsets of it" as *size- unreachable*. Formally: $$\operatorname {size-unreachable}(X) \iff \\\forall Y (Y \in X \iff Y \subset X \land |Y|<|X|)$$Now $V_\omega$ qualifies for such a set.

> What other examples of size-unreachable sets do $\sf ZFC$ prove to exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: My original answer made a very silly mistake!

Every size-unreachable $X$ is equal to $H_{\vert X\vert}$, and if $X$ is size-unreachable, then $\xi:=X\cap Ord$ is a regular limit ordinal. However, $\xi$ may not be a limit **cardinal**. For example, assuming $\mathsf{CH}$ the set $\mathsf{HC}$ (or $H_{\omega_1}$) of hereditarily countable sets is a size-unreachable set since $\vert\mathsf{HC}\vert=\omega_1$.

So the size-unreachable sets (other than $\emptyset$ and $V_\omega$) are exactly those $H_\kappa$s such that $\kappa$ is an uncountable regular cardinal satisfying $\vert H_\kappa\vert=\kappa$.

Comment: Do you mean "regular limit *cardinal*"? Why isn't $H_{\omega_1}$ under CH an example?

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Argh, good catch, fixed!