# Does ZFC prove existence of proper class many $H_\kappa$ sets with $|H_\kappa|=\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

This question is a follow up to a [prior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432930/what-examples-of-size-unreachable-sets-in-zfc) question

Let $H_\kappa$ be the set of all sets hereditarily strictly smaller than $\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is cardinal.

Is it a theorem of $\sf ZFC$ that we have a proper class of sets $H_\kappa$ such that $|H_\kappa|=\kappa$?

Comment: To address a common issue with terminology, often $H_\kappa$ is called "the set of all sets with hereditary cardinality less than $\kappa$" but defined as $\{x:|\operatorname{trcl}(x)|<\kappa\}.$ Based on the name one might expect the definition to be $\{x:|x|<\kappa\land \forall y\in \operatorname{trcl}(x)\; |y|<\kappa\}$ instead. These are only the same thing for regular $\kappa.$  For the former definition, the answer is "yes" (it holds at any strong limit cardinal), and for the latter the answer is "no" (per Asaf's answer).

Comment: (Would add too, just to be pedantic, that the "no" requires consistency of large cardinals, e.g. if ZFC refutes the existence of measurable cardinals, it proves the successor of every strong limit has this property.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, so "ZFC + no proper class of size-unreachable sets", proves existence of measurable cardinals?

Comment: No. The consistency of that theory implies the consistency of ZFC + there is a measurable cardinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $H_\kappa$ has size $\kappa$. First, note that $\kappa$ is regular, otherwise $[\kappa]^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}$ is a subset of $H_\kappa$, and by König's lemma that would have a strictly larger size.

Next, note that if $\kappa=\mu^+$, then this means that $2^\mu=\kappa$.

So, either $\sf GCH$ holds on a proper class or there is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals.

Since $\sf ZFC$ does not prove either claim, the answer is no.

Comment: hmm.., seeing that answer, it appears to me that only the empty set and $V_\omega$ are sets that ZFC manage to prove them being sets of all hereditarily strictly smaller subsets of them.

Comment: Pretty much. Yes.

Comment: No! I forgot $1$. So ZFC proves $\emptyset, 1, V_\omega$ to be size-unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Axiom of Choice, one can also explicitly compute the size of $H(\kappa)$ to be $2^{<\kappa}$, so that this question amounts to asking whether there is a proper class of cardinals with $\kappa=2^{<\kappa}$ (which Asaf answered already).

$H(\kappa)$ has size at least $2^{<\kappa}$ because the power set of each $\lambda<\kappa$ has transitive closure of size $<\kappa$, so each $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ is in $H(\kappa)$.

To see that is has size at most $2^{<\kappa}$, recall that each set can be uniquely coded as a relation on its cardinal (AC used here), and by Gödel's pairing, as a subset of its cardinal. So if $x\in H(\kappa)$, then one can find an ordinal $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $x$ is coded as a subset of $\lambda$. This injects $H(\kappa)$ into $2^{<\kappa}$.

Comment: ZFC does prove there is a proper class of cardinals with $\kappa=2^{<\kappa}$ (any strong limit cardinal). The disconnect is whether we mean $H_\kappa$ to be the "set of all sets with hereditary cardinality $<\kappa$" in the plain interpretation of the words, which fits Asaf's answer but does not have cardinality $2^{<\kappa}$ for $\kappa$ singular, or, what is more commonly meant, the set of all sets whose transitive closure has size $<\kappa$, which has the size $2^{<\kappa}$ for all $\kappa$ but fails Asaf's first paragraph.

Comment: What is the definition of $2^{<\kappa}$?